# Valgrind Invalid Read Error

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I have been unable to pinpoint the exact reason for my Valgrind error:

```
==3868== Invalid read of size 2
==3868==    at 0x100001F1F: Shrinker::Execute() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x1000029CD: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==  Address 0x100c12040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 7,201,152 free'd
==3868==    at 0x10000D94F: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==3868==    by 0x100001BD5: PNMreader::Execute() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001954: Source::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x10000299E: Filter::Update() (in ./proj4B)
==3868==    by 0x100001819: Image::Update() const (in ./proj4B)
```

I'm thinking it's due to my nested loop in Shrinker::Execute() and/or it's destructor:

```
void Shrinker::Execute() {
    int inWidth = 0, inHeight = 0, maxVal = 255;
    int halfWidth = 0, halfHeight = 0;

    inWidth = img1->GetWidth();
    inHeight = img1->GetHeight();

    halfWidth = inWidth / 2;
    halfHeight = inHeight / 2;

    buffer = (Pixel *) malloc(sizeof(Pixel)*halfWidth*halfHeight);

    int in = 0, out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < halfHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < halfWidth; j++) {
            in = i*2*inWidth+j*2;
            out = i*halfWidth+j;
            buffer[out] = img1->GetPixels()[in];
        }
    }

    img.ResetSize(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    img.SetMaxVal(maxVal);
    img.SetPixels(buffer);

}   // end Shrinker::Execute()
```

I've attempted making every minor adjustment I could think of to both the nested loop and the malloc in Shrinker, to no avail. It's destructor frees the buffer and sets it to NULL. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the definition of `Pixel`.  `malloc` should not be used in C++ as it does not actually begin the lifetime of objects that have non-trivial constructors

Comment: If you suspect a destructor problem it'd be useful to show that destructor

Comment: where is Filter::Update coming from? Perhaps the error is coming inside `ResetSize`, `SetMaxVal`, or `SetPixels`  or `GetPixels()`, you haven't shown the code for those. For example maybe this is actually a buffer overflow in `GetPixels`.

Comment: Compile your code with debugging information enabled and optimisation disabled (`-O0 -g` for gcc/clang) and you'll get much better messages out of valgrind - including line-numbers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the Pixel definition is just a struct with unsigned char r, g, b data members. The destructor in question only does free(buffer); buffer = NULL; Shrinker resides in Filters which is inherited from Filter and the Update() function pushes everything in my driver through the pipeline.

Comment: It's always better to post your code than to describe it

Comment: To get answers that aren't guesses you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know the purpose of your code. However, maybe you use wrong parameter in below code:

> ```
> in = i*2*inWidth+j*2;
> ```

It should be:

> ```
> in = i*2*halfwidth+j*2;
> ```

I think.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause, it looks like that code produces a skewed image and I still get the same valgrind error. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but since its an access into a block that has been previously free'd - something is destroying the buffer allocated in `Shrinker::Execute` - if the only place that is free'd is your destructor, then you've probably got a bad (possibly temporary) copy created of your `Shrinker` - this would happen if you returned a Shrinker object from a function for example.

You need to ensure that you've either prevented copies from getting created or correctly implemented the copy constructor and assignment operators.